# Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.StageName at line 6 column 13

Tags: trigger, opportunity

```
trigger UpdateLease on Opportunity ( After update) {

   List<ID> OppIds = New List<ID>();

    for (opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
        if (opp.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase = 'Closed won') {
            OppIds.add(opp.Id);   
        }
   }
        if(!OppIds.isEmpty()){
        List<Product2> products = [Select id from Product2 where Opportunity /*Lookup Field*/ in : oppIds];

        for(Product2 prod : products){
        prod.Available_for_lease =true;
        }
        update products;
}
}
```

I am new to apex please help. I am creating a trigger that will update the checkbox in the products if the opportunity stage was set to "closed won".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct link between products and opportunities. You need to query OpportunityLineItem to get the products:

```
Opportunity[] wonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.StageName == 'closed won') {
        wonOpps.add(record);
    }
}
if(wonOpps.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunitLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :wonOpps)];
for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = true;
}
update products;
```

I think you might be doing this wrong though... a product is a generic item (e.g. a Snickers candy bar), not a specific item (e.g. *the* Snickers candy bar). You might want to build a way to associate assets with opportunities, because that's what assets are meant to be used for.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use `equalsIgnoreCase` is wrong in your condition. Try one of,

```
if (opp.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed won')) {
            OppIds.add(opp.Id);   
}
```

Or

```
if (opp.StageName == 'Closed won') {
            OppIds.add(opp.Id);   
}
```

**EDIT:**
`Product2` is for keep your sales item and `OpportunityLineItem` is which are attached into a specific `Opportunity` AFAIK. If you really need to access `Product2`, sfdcfox have already answered you.

```
Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunitLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :wonOpps)];
for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = true;
}
```

But what I feel is you have to have this checkbox on `OpportunityLineItem` and update it. Check with your use case.

Comment: thanks, what is the relationship between the opportunity and products? im being completely lost here...  should i create a look up of products in the opportunity?

Comment: Ya there is no direct relationship and `OpportunityLineItem` is the one which get attached into an `Opportunity`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger UpdateLease on Opportunity ( After update) {

    Opportunity[] wonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
        for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
            if(record.StageName == 'closed won') {
                wonOpps.add(record);
            }
        }
            if(wonOpps.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
       Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :wonOpps)];
       for(Product2 product: products) {
         product.Available_for_Lease__c = false;
       }
       update products;
}
```

thank you sfdcfox.. it worked for me..